# Excel table with X and Y values doesn't convert in point layer correctly

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, xy

I have an Excel table with the X and Y values that I have added to QGIS 3.18.
Y want to georeference this table in points, so I follow these steps:

Process toolbox -> vector creation -> create point layer from table

I have completed X and Y values correctly and the CRS too. It is EPSG:4326.
The problem is that points are not displayed correctly as the photo shows, they appear aligned. They appear in Lima, the city where I am working, but not correctly.

[image]

Comment: Not clear about georeferencing points. Do you want to use these points to georeference an image?

Comment: Can you show a piece of your excel table and how you entered the value in the processing tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Padmanabha and @katagena for your help. Yes I had to be more clear.
But I could find an answer and it solved my problem.

This my excel table in .xlsx:
[image]

IN THIS CASE, the COORDINATES are in the same field. Instead of using the extract function of Excel to take it to another file, we can transform it to .CSV

1. Duplicate the Excel file.
2. Save the file in COMMA DELIMITED .CSV format
3. Open this new file with the “NOTE PAD” application
4. In NOTEPAD, replace the semicolon (;) values with comma (,) as it is the CSV's y-coordinate format. Select the save option.
5. Load the table as a vector file in QGIS.
6. Finally you must use the toolbox option called "create point layer from table"

Now the correct result is this.
[image]

Comment: Kindly accept this as answer.